# Phabricator showing duplicates commits after git reset

Tags: git, phabricator

We use Phabricator to do code review using the Audit application. When there's a problem with a commit we do `git reset` and `push -f` to rewrite the history. Phabricator still showing the old commits when viewing an task.
 Is there a way that Phabricator remove the commits that doesn't exist in the git repository anymore?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you revert by that sort of approach on any VCS, Git included, you aren't "erasing" previous commits at all. You're actually creating a new commit that is the same as the commit you were rolling back to. It's a necessary feature of a VCS, just in case someone messes up the revert and erases something important.

Yes, there are ways to [rewrite history in an irreversible way](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), but your method isn't doing that.

So, since Git didn't actually erase the old commit, Phabricator will not delete it. It will just show the new commit.